# How can I use tensorboard with tf.estimator.Estimator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am considering to move my code base to [tf.estimator.Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), but I cannot find an example on how to use it in combination with tensorboard summaries.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

# Declare list of features, we only have one real-valued feature
def model(features, labels, mode):
    # Build a linear model and predict values
    W = tf.get_variable("W", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
    b = tf.get_variable("b", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
    y = W*features['x'] + b
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - labels))

    # Summaries to display for TRAINING and TESTING
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)    
    tf.summary.image("X", tf.reshape(tf.random_normal([10, 10]), [-1, 10, 10, 1])) # dummy, my inputs are images

    # Training sub-graph
    global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train = tf.group(optimizer.minimize(loss), tf.assign_add(global_step, 1))

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=y,loss= loss,train_op=train)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model, model_dir='/tmp/tf')
# define our data set
x=np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y=np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn({"x": x}, y, 4, num_epochs=1000)

for epoch in range(10):
    # train
    estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=100)
    # evaluate our model
    estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn, steps=10)
```

How can I display my two summaries in tensorboard? Do I have to register a hook in which I use a `tf.summary.FileWriter` or something else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

EDIT:
Upon testing (in v1.1.0, and probably in later versions as well), it is apparent that `tf.estimator.Estimator` will automatically write summaries for you. I confirmed this using OP's code and tensorboard.

(Some poking around r1.4 leads me to conclude that this automatic summary writing occurs due to [`tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L204).)

Ultimately, the automatic summarizing is accomplished with the use of hooks, so if you wanted to customize the Estimator's default summarizing, you could do so using hooks. Below are the (edited) details from the original answer.

---

You'll want to use hooks, formerly known as [monitors](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/monitors). (Linked is a conceptual/quickstart guide; the short of it is that the notion of hooking into / monitoring training is built into the Estimator API. A bit confusingly, though, it doesn't seem like the deprecation of monitors for hooks is really documented except in a deprecation annotation in the actual source code...)

Based on your usage, it looks like r1.2's [`SummarySaverHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SummarySaverHook) fits your bill.

```
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
    SAVE_EVERY_N_STEPS,
    output_dir='/tmp/tf',
    summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())
```

You may want to customize the hook's initialization parameters, as by providing an explicity SummaryWriter or writing every N seconds instead of N steps.

If you pass this into the `EstimatorSpec`, you'll get your customized Summary behavior:

```py
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=y,loss=loss,
                                  train_op=train,
                                  training_hooks=[summary_hook])
```

EDIT NOTE:
A previous version of this answer suggested passing the `summary_hook` into `estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=5, hooks=[summary_hook])`. This does not work because `tf.summary.merge_all()` has to be called in the same context as your model graph.

Comment: I tried the code above but it crashes with the error message: "Exactly one of scaffold or summary_op must be provided."

I think tf.summary.merge_all() return None. Do I have to add the summary to a certain collection?

Comment: `tf.summary.merge_all()` is out of scope of metrics created within `input_fn` so this will not work.

Comment: Good catch. Answer edited. Specifically, `Estimator.train` calls `model_fn` in its own default graph, so `merge_all`, called outside of `model_fn`, is not able to find the summary nodes, and returns `None` as per its spec.

Comment: the question for me is, can we have two hooks, one as you said, as summary hook, another one shall print out loss as loss hook

Answer (score 8):

For me this worked **without** adding any hooks or `merge_all` calls. I just added some `tf.summary.image(...)` in my `model_fn` and when I train the model they magically appear in tensorboard. Not sure what the exact mechanism is, however. I'm using TensorFlow 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

`estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model, model_dir='/tmp/tf')`

Code `model_dir='/tmp/tf'` means estimator write all logs to `/tmp/tf`, then run `tensorboard --log.dir=/tmp/tf`, open you browser with url: http://localhost"6006 ,you can see the graphic

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `SummarySaverHook` with `tf.summary.merger_all()` as the summary_op *in the model_fn itself*. Pass this hook to the `training_hooks` param of the `EstimatorSpec` constructor in your model_fn.

I don't think what @jagthebeetle said is exactly applicable here. As the hooks that you transfer to the `estimator.train` method cannot be run for the summaries that you define in your model_fn, since they won't be added to the `merge_all` op as they remain bounded by the scope of `model_fn`