# How to examine the results of a tensorflow.data.Dataset based model.train input_fn

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-datalab

I am learning how to use the tf.data.Dataset api.  I am using the sample code provided by google for their coursera tensorflow class.  Specifically I am working with the c_dataset.ipynb notebook [here.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/tree/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/03_tensorflow)

This notebook has a model.train routine which looks like this:

```
model.train(input_fn = get_train(), steps = 1000)
```

The get_train() routine eventually calls code which uses the tf.data.Dataset api with this snippet of code:

```
filenames_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filename)
# read lines from text files 
# this results in a dataset of textlines from all files
textlines_dataset = filenames_dataset.flat_map(tf.data.TextLineDataset)
# Parse text lines as comma-separated values (CSV)
# this does the decoder function for each textline
dataset = textlines_dataset.map(decode_csv)
```

The comments do a pretty explanation of what happens.  Later this routine will return like so:

```
    # return the features and label as a tensorflow node, these
    # will trigger file load operations progressively only when
    # needed.
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Is there anyway to evaluate the result for one iteration?  I tried to something like this but it fails.

```
# Try to read what its using from the cvs file.
one_batch_the_csv_file = get_train()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  result = sess.run(one_batch_the_csv_file)

print(one_batch_the_csv_file)
```

Per the suggestion from Ruben below, I added  this

I moved on to the next set of labs in this class where they introduce tensorboard and I get some graphs but still no inputs or outputs.  With that said, here is a more complete set of source.

```
# curious he did not do this
# I am guessing because the output is so verbose
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)  # putting back in since, tf.train.LoggingTensorHook mentions it

def train_and_evaluate(output_dir, num_train_steps):

  # Added this while trying to get input vals from csv.
  # This gives an error about scafolding
  # summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook()
  # SAVE_EVERY_N_STEPS,
  #  summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())



  # To convert a model to distributed train and evaluate do four things
  estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(                         # 1. Estimator
                          model_dir = output_dir,
                          feature_columns = feature_cols, 
                          hidden_units=[160, 80, 40, 20],
                          n_classes=2,
                          config=tf.estimator.RunConfig().replace(save_summary_steps=2)  # 2. run config
                                                                                          # ODD. he mentions we need a run config in the videos, but it was missing in the lab
                                                                                          # notebook.  Later I found the bug report which gave me this bit of code.
                                                                                          # I got a working TensorBoard when I changed this from save_summary_steps=10 to 2.
                          )# 


  # .. also need the trainspec to tell the estimator how to get training data
  train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
                                    input_fn = read_dataset('./taxi-train.csv', mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN), # make sure you use the dataset api
                                    max_steps = num_train_steps)
#                                    training_hook=[summary_hook])       # Added this while trying to get input vals from csv.

  # ... also need this
  # serving and training-time inputs are often very different
  exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('exporter', serving_input_receiver_fn = serving_input_fn)




  # .. also need an EvalSpec which controls the evaluation and
  # the checkpointing of the model since they happen at the same time
  eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
                                    input_fn = read_dataset('./taxi-valid.csv', mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL), # make sure you use the dataset api
                                    steps=None, # evals on 100 batches
                                    start_delay_secs = 1, # start evaluating after N secoonds. orig was 1.  3 seemed to fail?
                                    throttle_secs = 10, # eval no more than every 10 secs. Can not be more frequent than the checkpoint config specified in the run config.
                                    exporters = exporter)  # how to export the model for production.

  tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(
                                estimator,
                                train_spec,  # 3. Train Spec
                                eval_spec)   # 4. Eval Spec


OUTDIR = './model_trained'
shutil.rmtree(OUTDIR, ignore_errors = True) # start fresh each time
TensorBoard().start(OUTDIR)
# need to let this complete before running next cell 


# call the above routine
train_and_evaluate(OUTDIR, num_train_steps = 6000)  # originally 2000. 1000 after reset shows only projectors
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what kind of information you want to extract. If you are interested in step N, as a general answer:

1. If you want exactly the results, just run with `model.train(input_fn = get_train(), steps = N)`.
2. Check train module functions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train) for specific content in a determined step.

If you search for step you will find different classes:

- [CheckpointSaverHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointSaverHook): Saves checkpoints every N steps or seconds.
- [LoggingTensorHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/LoggingTensorHook): Prints the given tensors every N local steps, every N seconds, or at end.
- [ProfilerHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ProfilerHook): Captures CPU/GPU profiling information every N steps or seconds.
- [SummarySaverHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SummarySaverHook): Saves summaries every N steps.
- Etc. (there are more, just check what can be useful for you).

Comment: I'm looking for the contents of the input dataframe for a single step.  ie. I would like to see the feature columns.

Comment: I would go for LoggingTensorHook, then.

Comment: Thank you again Ruben.  I'm trying to figure it out.  I'm looking the LoggingTensorHook page now.

Comment: Hmm. I am using estimator api.  This post has comments regarding how to add tensorboard to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782767/how-can-i-use-tensorboard-with-tf-estimator-estimator

Comment: Hmm. This does not work.  I'll post an incomplete answer below with more details.

Comment: Update on the original post, please.

Comment: I moved the partial answer with the additional code from the next lab to the first question per your advice.