# how to get tf.summary in the tf.estimator.Estimator API to save variables for tensorboard during EVALUATE runs?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator

I'm using the tf.estimator API on tf 1.9

I have multiple output losses and would like to capture each individual loss for both the TRAINING and EVAL steps in tensorboard.

Inside the model_fn, I have defined several tf.summary.scalar such as:

```
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(
            labels[label1], predictions[label1]))
tf.summary.scalar('loss1', loss1)

loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(
            labels[label2], predictions[label2]))
tf.summary.scalar('loss2', loss2)

combined_loss = tf.reduce_mean([loss1, loss2])
```

These are displayed in tensorboard only for TRAINING runs. For EVAL runs I only see eval_metric_ops recorded as well as the combined_loss, but not individual losses.

I have tried adding explicit evaluation_hooks inside model_fn to take the tf.summary.merge_all() operation as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782767/how-can-i-use-tensorboard-with-tf-estimator-estimator)

```
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=100,
                                    output_dir=params['model_dir'],
                                    summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions,
                                  loss=combined_loss,
                                  train_op=train_op,
                                  eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,
                                  evaluation_hooks=[summary_hook]
                                 )
```

The results are the same, i.e. no tf.summary.scalar saved during EVAL.
How can I get EVAL runs to write out tf.summary?

Comment: Found [this](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15332) in the github thread


`summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=save_steps, output_dir='summary',summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all)`


`eval_results = self._estimator.evaluate(input_fn=self.validation_dataset, hooks=[summary_hook])`


but not exactly sure where this code goes? 
doesn't tf.summary.merge_all() need to be in model_fn?